# PHP cascading (passing) subsequent returns through 3 functions

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have been through S/O and have not found this specific problem although my inexperience may mean I've searched by the wrong terms. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Basically, I have three PHP functions (within a class named KeyPositions). The first is called by passing an argument; the second function is called by the first and then produces an array that is passed on to the third function. By using echo and print_r I can see that everything is in place as it is being passed. The problem is occurring on the return from the final function (the 3rd). While my foreach/echo test (just before the return) shows every element in the array is present, that is not what I'm getting once I look at what is returned to the original call. Here are the steps:

Originating call: `$keypositions = KeyPositions::getKPSponsor($session_userid);`

Second return (where the problem starts?): `return self::getKPList($sponsor_list);`

Third function: `public static function getKPList($arr)`

Test before return (shows array contents perfectly): `foreach($kppositions as $s) { echo $s['kp_root'],"<br>"; }`

Return statement: `return $kppositions;`

But when I go back to the original function call and run this test I only receive a subset of what I would've expected from the return (above): `foreach($keypositions as $t) { echo $t['id'],"<br>"; }`

Is there something that I'm missing when an array is passed from one function to the next? All arrays are associative. I intentionally did not include the lengthy code within each of the functions because the functions themselves seem to be performing perfectly based on the test I do just before each return (meaning what I expect to be inside the array is fully intact at each step). I believe this may have something to do with the passing of returns from one function to the next? Any direction here would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Okay. Sorry. My thought was to not muddy things with all the code.** Here it is. Keep in mind, this is for testing and not for final (e.g., no PHP injection work yet.)

```
public static function getKPSponsor($userid)
    {
        return self::getKPSponsors('positions.jobholder_uid = "' .$userid. '"');
    }

    public static function getKPSponsors($criteria = '')
    {
        $sponsor_levels = array();
        $sponsor_list = array();
        $criteria = " WHERE $criteria";
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection(); 
        $sql_query_sponsors = "SELECT positions.position_id AS id, jobholder_uid AS uid FROM positions $criteria";
        $result_sponsors = $mysqli->query($sql_query_sponsors);

        while ($sponsor_level = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_sponsors)){
            $sponsor_id = $sponsor_level['uid'];
            $sponsor_level['items'] = self::getKPSponsors('positions.positionmgr_uid = "' .$sponsor_id. '"');
                $sponsor_levels[] = $sponsor_level;
        }

        foreach($sponsor_levels as $r) {
            $sponsor_list[] = $r['id'];
        }

        mysqli_free_result($result_sponsors);
        unset($r);
        return self::getKPList($sponsor_list);
    }

    public static function getKPList($arr)
    {
        $kppositions = array();
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

        $sql_query_keypositions = "SELECT key_positions.kp_id AS id, key_positions.kp_root, key_positions.kp_area, key_positions.c_ksa, key_positions.c_relationship, key_positions.c_rare, key_positions.urgency, positions.jobholder_uid, master.last_name, CONCAT(master.first_name,' ',master.last_name) AS full_name FROM key_positions INNER JOIN positions ON positions.position_id = key_positions.kp_sponsor INNER JOIN master ON positions.jobholder_uid = master.email_address WHERE key_positions.kp_sponsor IN (" . implode(",", $arr) . ");";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query_keypositions);

        while ($kp3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $kppositions[] = $kp3;
        }

        foreach($kppositions as $s) { // My testing ...
            echo $s['kp_root'],"<br>";
        }


        mysqli_free_result($result);
        return $kppositions;
    }
```

In case this helps further, the output from my test BEFORE the return yields:

1000014
1000015
1000016
1000012
1000006
1000022
1000017
1000018
1000019
1000020
1000021
1000008
1000009
1000010
1000011
1000004
1000005
1000007
1000013
1000003
1000001
1000002

The output AFTER the return yields:

1000001
1000002

Comment: Why not do an array_merge() and return them?

Comment: While we appreciate that you did not show the full extended code, you should at least provide a [mre] that illustrates the basic issue - by just being given these more or less context-less single lines, it is rather hard to figure out what is actually going on. You can mock this with hard-coded dummy arrays instead of doing anything dynamically, but at least shows us something that we can actually _run_, and see what you are talking about.

Comment: Rather than showing bits and pieces of where you think the problem is, can you provide a more complete example to demonstrate?

Comment: I am not trying to merge the arrays. Each array being passed is then being used (manipulated) to create a subsequent array The final array seems to be the problem because it is correct just before the return but doesn't end up right after the return.

Comment: Sorry. Code added ... thank you.

Comment: New Info: As I continue testing, it appears this might be an Asynchronous issue? It seems that the return passed to the final function is NOT a 'final' return because it circles back to the second function several times and that might be why the final iteration has only two (2) elements. Can anyone confirm this? I was under the impression that PHP was - by default - sequential and not asynchronous so I thought that once a return statement is issued that function would halt?